# Overriding append method in stringBuilder?

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the append method in the StringBuilder class. I was asked how can we override the append() method in the StringBuilder class while stringBuilder class is final. Is the same logic applicable for overriding toString() in String class while String class is final? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding toString in the String class is overriding a method of `java.lang.Object` in `java.lang.String`. Since the class is declared final, you can't derive from it and hence not override the toString-method, which is a special case in String, since it returns the String itself.

Overriding a method in a final class is impossible. And `append ()` isn't a method in Object, so they are not equivalent, but you can't override append either.

Comment: I believe you mean `extend`ing a final class, not overriding. Overriding final methods is impossible.

Comment: In fact, in `String` the `toString()` method is implemented as `return this;`.

Comment: Of course String needs a `toString()` method. Otherwise it would return its identity hash (à la `Object`) and that would just be evil.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't really override a `final` method, there might be some bytecode level magic that would allow you to do that, but I'm not sure it is worth it.

You can create a wrapper class, something like `MyStringBuilder` and for every one of the methods in `StringBuilder` create a method that delegates to an instance of `StringBuilder`, then you can modify the `append` methods as you see fit. There is a catch with this approach and that is that you can't access `private` variables defined in `StringBuilder` although that might not be such a big deal for your use case. YMMV

Comment: +1 for not being worth it. You can do anything you want if you were to write your own `javac` implementation, including ignoring the final keyword or who knows what else. But that doesn't make it a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

A class declared `final` can't be extended, so there is no way to override any method of it.

A class which is not declared `final` can be extended, but any method declared `final` can't be overridden.

Answer (score -1):

Those classes are final by design. The API designers didn't want to deal with the added complexity of making those classes a base class for inheritance.

Instead of inheritance, you can use delegation and create your own StringBuilder class that uses an instance of java.lang.StringBuilder as delegate. This makes it trivial to create your own append methods.